# Undo preventDefault() method

Tags: jquery

I was wondering if there was any way of "undoing" the preventDefault() method on submit. I have this code that does the trick, but I want to know if there is a more efficient way of doing it.

```
var $form = $('form');
var canSubmit = false;

$form.data('working', false);

$form.submit(function(e){
    if (form.validations.form($form)) {
        if (!$form.data('working')) {
            $form.data('working', true);

            if (canSubmit) {
                // make the post here
            } else {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.get(BASE+'file.txt', function(response){
                    $form.data('canSubmit', true);
                    $form.submit();
                });
            }
        }
    } else {
        $form.data('working', false);
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

This is because I have to read and write a file after the validations are done and only after that make the post to the page.
The post can't be done by ajax.

Thanks

Comment: Does something like this work? `$('form').unbind('submit');` Been a while since I worked with this, so apologies if not!

Comment: but if I unbind the submit it won't make the post

Comment: Yes you're right, I've only used this with `click` not submit. I didn't give that a thought! My bad

Comment: It looks like you are doing two-step checking, so no, you can't just *undo a preventDefault* call as it is on a separate instance of `e`. Can you please explain your "I have to read and write a file after the validations are done" comment, as the code appears incomplete.

Comment: after I make the first validations (name, email, etc.) I need to make a psedo ajax and only after that response the post is to continue

Comment: basically I was wondering if I could make the preventDefault at the top and after all is done, continue with the post, therefore undoing the preventDefault done

Comment: Please show all your code.

Comment: that's all my code in the submit function

Comment: I've added my GET ajax call

Comment: Thanks. That was the missing key part :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't undo the `e.preventDefault()` as you are dealing with a later instance of `e` by the time you submit.

`return false` does the same as `e.preventDefault()` *and* `e.stopPropagation()`, so you can simplify your code a little though by simply returning your flag.

```
var $form = $('form');
var canSubmit = false;

$form.data('working', false);
$form.submit(function(e){
    if (form.validations.form($form)) {
        if (!$form.data('working')) {
            $form.data('working', true);
            if (!canSubmit) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.get(BASE+'file.txt', function(response){
                    canSubmit = true;
                    $form.submit();  // trigger recursive call
                });
            }
        }
    } else {
        $form.data('working', false);
    }
    return canSubmit;
});
```

Comment: @Kup: Should help. Basically your function exits immediately after calling the async `$.get`, so you cannot possibly go back in time to modify the previous submit :)